# How to update the AMI of the instance without loosing data? and the instance has two EBS volumes which EBS volume should i take snapshot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, amazon-ami

How to update the AMI of the instance without loosing data? and the instance has two EBS volumes (root and secondary) which EBS volume should i take snapshot? to replicate the original instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can't update the AMI of an instance without replacing it with a new instance. Typically you simply run the operating system updates - yum update / apt update & upgrade / windows update. So long as the OS is still supported that typically does everything most people need, unless you need features in a newer OS that aren't available in an older OS.

If you want a VM based on a different AMI you have to manually create a new instance, install required software, migrate your data, etc. You can of course attach any volumes from that instance to another VM, which is best done after the old instance is stopped.

Take a snapshot of all volume before you do *anything*.

What exactly are you trying to achieve here?